# What can I do with vegetable water?

Tags: vegetables, water, steaming

I just steamed some vegetables and the water below is greenish-yellow vegetable sweat basically. I don't want to waste any thing unless I have to for a valid reason. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 21):

- Make bread with it (let it cool enough that you don't kill the yeast,
  first.)
- Make soup with it.

Comment: Soup is actually a good advice, since soup is, in a very rough way, just throwing vegetables at some water and, well, fire it up! Also, I'm kinda used to eat soup as the first dish on the table, so, it is nearly a "must have" and it can stay good for up to 2 days (if properly stored).

Answer (score 20):

I've read that if you can't or don't use it for your own consumption, that houseplants really love it (after it's cooled, of course).

Comment: Yea, give that water to plants .. That will be great idea

Comment: And only if you boil without salt!

Comment: @Stephie Good point, though the asker says they steamed the vegetables and there's no point adding salt when steaming.

Comment: Seems a good idea but... Won't it be plant-canibalism?

Comment: What do you think is compost?

Comment: You're right XD

Answer (score 9):

I usually add some other veggies "disposable parts" to that water before boiling, so i make a vegetabel stock, and then use it to make risotto

Answer (score 5):

When steaming vegetables, I'm often making something that tastes good with stock or gravy. The vegetable water makes a great base for both. If you use instant granules, you can just pour the steaming water into the powder for extra flavour.

Answer (score 3):

Vegetable water is totally harmless and can often be used as a base for a broth. If meat is an option, fortify it with chicken broth..or better yet, use it to make your own beef/chicken broth. If desired, you can also fortify it with more savory tasting vegetables. Celery and carrots usually impart a nice flavor. Just make sure u strain the solids.

You can also use the veggie water as a substitute for water in your morning smoothies, especially if there's color and flavor in it.

Comment: Welcome! A couple note: health and nutrition are off-topic here, so in addition to not allowing questions about them, we ask that you avoid discussing them in your answers. Also, no need for signatures - your username and image will be on all your posts.

Comment: Apologies for not being fully accustomed to the format here. Thank you for taking the time to inform me. I look forward to contributing in a fashion that is most suitable.

Comment: No worries, there's a lot of information in [help] (and on [meta]) but we definitely don't expect everyone to read it all first. Glad to have your answers!

Answer (score 2):

I like using vegetable water to cook pasta, particularly when I'm going to not use a thick sauce (e.g. tossing the pasta with olive oil, dried herbs, and some grated parmesan).

I also use it to cook rice, in the same vein as above (i.e. not with thick sauces).

Answer (score 1):

You practically have vegetable tea. Options related to its condition are:

**Actual state:** Just drink it at your preferred temperature. You may be able to sense its flavor, but it is as satisfying as normal water anyway.

**Hydrating water:** Some salt, Sodium bicarbonate, citric juice and Aid is ready for your training, excercise, Hangover.

**Flavored water:** Lemon juice can make it a good meal companion if you are fine with unsweetened drinks. You have two more options there.

- Plus of Herbal tea for a more focused flavor (Chaya leaf [Cnidoscolus aconitifolius] is simillar to brocolli water taste). Temperature is your choice.
- A little of salt and chilli powder* if you are related to the joy of drinking the broth made by eating picks of square chopped aliments (fruit, sausage, cheese, chips, corn, etc.) as a snack. Preferrably warm/hot.

**Consommé:** Chilli powder*, soy/hot sauce*, lemon juice, salt, peper, garlic, matching spices, chopped onion and green chilli, milk products and dressings, make it a good clear soup to drink it warm/hot just as it is. You can also add some complements in little pieces like bread (croutons), solid cheese (Panela, Gouda, etc.), more vegetables or even use it to cook your ramen noodles.

**General purpose Broth:** The consommé serve as a great seasoning for grains, legumes, meat, seafood and vegetable hot soup.

Don't consider only wheat flour to make bread with the water. Corn and other wheats can serve great for making good complements such as tortillas an other region specific (ussually salty) bread shapes.

This is as far as I go by experience and wide taste. Would be nice to know experience of a rice and brewing adventurers.

*Good chilli product brands are Tajín, Valentina/Tamazula and Tabasco. A nice and bitterseet (commonly not considered hot) sauce is called *Chamoy*.